# How many recursively definable groups are there on $\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: group-theory, computability

How many non-isomorphic, (non-free), non-trivial, recursively definable groups are there on $\mathbb{N}$? I know we can at least get 1. Let $F:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$ be the "natural bijection". By this, I mean:
$$F(0)=0$$ Now, if $n$ is even: $$F(n)=\frac{n}{2}$$ And if $n$ odd: $$F(n)=-\frac{n+1}{2}$$ Consider $(\mathbb{N}, \triangle)$ where we $n \triangle m=F^{-1}(F(n)+F(m))$. Note that $(\mathbb{N},\triangle)\cong (\mathbb{Z},+)$ as group structures.

Note also, since we are working with recursively definable groups, there is no more that $\aleph_0$ many. So, I know that there is at least one and at most countably many.

Comment: All the free groups on finitely many or countably many elements are recursively definable so: lots.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: That's cheating! You're right. I just edited the question to get rid of those.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : Actually, what is the explicit bijection you can use to construct a free group in $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: For example, the free group on $2$ elements: Start enumerating group elements by length: $1,a,b,a^{-1},b^{-1},a^2,ab,ab^{-1},ba,b^2,ba^{-1},a^{-1}b,\dots$ It's not hard. Canonical words for free group elements are easy - just remove all instances of $aa^{-1}$, $a^{-1}a$, $bb^{-1}$, and $b^{-1}b$ from the word. Multiplication is just concatenation and reduction to normal form.

Comment: Every infinite finitely generated group with a solvable word problem has a "computable copy", i.e., is isomorphic to $\mathbf{N}$ with a computable law. This provides plenty of examples (countably many, of course). Conversely every computable group law on $\mathbf{N}$ defining a finitely generated group, has a solvable word problem. On the other hand there are also computable laws on $\mathbf{N}$ that are infinitely generated groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any integer $n$, take the direct sum of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and countably many copies of $\mathbb{Z_2}$.

We can find an explicit injection by looking at integers of the form 
$$2^kp_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}\cdots p_k^{e_k}\cdots,$$
("infinite" product), where $0\le k\le n-1$, the $p_i$ are the odd primes, and $e_i=0$ or $e_i=1$ for all $i$, with only finitely many of the $e_i$ equal to $1$. The addition is defined in the natural way. To get a recursive bijection with the natural numbers, map the $m$-th integer of the type described above to $m$.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see how this works out on $\mathbb{N}$ explicitly. Could you explain? for example, if we set $p=5$ and if $\cdot$ is our operation, what is $4 \cdot 12$ and $7^{-1}$?

Comment: So you want an explicit bijection?

Comment: Right, preferably things which are recursively definable and explicit.

Comment: The answer seems perfectly clear to me - if you're in a position to ask the question, you can certainly fill in the routine details.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @CarlMummert: You're right. I should have done it myself. I will add the next requirement "groups of infinite order" and do it myself.

Comment: You can make it easier on yourself by taking $k+nb$ where $b$ is the binary number written $e_1e_2\dots$. Then it is a bijection with $\mathbb N$.

Comment: I turned automatically to the usual "indexing" tricks. Your procedures are substantially more natural.

Answer (score 2):

Even easier than the free group comment.

Pick $n\in\mathbb N, n>1$. For each $k\in\mathbb N$, write $k$ in base $n$, yielding an infinite sequence of digits from $0$ to $p-1$. Treat this as an element of $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$. Add two numbers by the same algorithm you'd normally add by, but don't carry the ones.

Then you get groups of the form: $\bigoplus_{i\in\mathbb N} \mathbb Z/\mathbb nZ$.

For different $n$, this yields non-isomorphic groups because in each group, since there are elements of degree $n$ and no elements of any higher degree.